# Webrtc issue - Skipping STUN server because of address type mis-match

Tags: meteor, webrtc, peerjs

I have been working with Webrtc project in the meteor platform. I am facing a strange issue whenever the peers are connecting from different network.

Here's step to reproduction -

1. Open https://sharebros.meteorapp.com/ and click on send button
   then complete the entire file transfer process (by sharing the connection id with peers on different networks)
2. after that open about:webrtc in firefox
3. then you can see connection logs and the error is also present in the logs

Here's the error -

```
Skipping STUN server because of address type mismatch
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

The project is deployed in Meteor Galaxy, and I have enabled ipv6 support as well.

Comment: Is this really a *problem*? It’s just an informative message. Are you saying it’s skipping *all* servers and thus can’t establish a connection? Then perhaps the client can only use IPv6 but you have only IPv4 servers in your list?